# Get the ASCII number of a character(Python3)

Tags: python, ascii

I wrote a code that converts numbers  1 - 501 in ASCII, it works but I'm looking for a shorter path.

```
l = list(range(1,501))
for i in l:
    ix = [int(d) for d in str(i)]
    ix = str(ix).replace("[","")
    ix = ix.replace("]","")
    ix = ix.replace(",","")
    ix = ix.replace(" ","")
    ix = [ord(x) for x in ix]
    print(ix)
```

I tried to write, as shown below, but an error occurs.

```
l = list(range(1,501))
for i in l:
    i = [ord(x) for x in i]
    >>TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
    print(i)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please show the expected output. Your code seems to be trying to convert each digit in each of those numbers to a character, but that's not what you asked in your question. I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: ASCII only has 128 characters.

Comment: What do you mean, convert numbers 1-501 in ASCII? That does not make much sense. Do you want [str(c).encode('ascii') for c in range(1, 501)]?

Comment: "It works"? It produces something, but what do you want a lot of lists with character codes in them for? In the second piece, you do `for x in i` where i is an integer. That has no meaning.

Comment: a range of numbers from 1-5, the result : [49]
[50]
[51]
[52]
[53]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is your second code snippet with one small change. Note in the comprehension where **for x in i** is replaced by **for x in str(i)**.  It now produces the same output as your first code snippet.

```
l = list(range(1,501))
for i in l:
    i = [ord(x) for x in str(i)]
    print(i)
```